# How well do erlang timer scales

Tags: erlang

I have a timer project requirement in my web server. Some effects done by clients operations at the server needs to be reset after sometime the had occurred. To do this, I intend to use erlang:start_timer/3 function to send a reset message to a process that does the resetting for each effects. This is ok with few client's operations coming in. The question is, does erlang timer scales very well as the number of current effects to time for reset increases?

Answer (score 1):

Don't guess, don't ask, try it and measure. Nobody know your use case and requirements better than you. Is it for profit? Then you are paid for it. Is it as a hobby, then be used to it. It is an integral part of your job.